# Moving and teleporting an object in the x direction forever

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, parallax

So I have had this problem that has been frustrating me for a while, I need to get 3 game objects to move at %speed of a base set speed. That part is easy. Now the problem is that i just cannot get it to move to a set position, then teleport infront of me and continue,
Help would be much appreciated!

[What I'm going for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iJBy.jpg)

[Current code](https://pastebin.com/5uQWC4hj)

Update function

```
    void Update()
{
    //suuuuper bad implemantation
    float newPos = Mathf.Repeat(Time.time * globalspeed, 20);
    Ground1.transform.position = startpos + new Vector2(reset, upPos1) * newPos * Ground1Speed;
    Ground2.transform.position = startpos + new Vector2(reset, upPos2) * newPos  * Ground2Speed;
    Ground3.transform.position = startpos + new Vector2(reset, upPos3) * newPos * Ground3Speed;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you want but if I'm right, you want 3 game objects to move on the ground (like a driving car) and disappear when they get to the end, then appear in the start position and move again in infinite loops. If I'm right you should try this:

```
public float objectSpeed;

void update()
{
    MoveObject();
}

void MoveObject()
{

    objectSpeed = 20; //Set the object speed
    
    if (transform.position.x >= 120) //Set the position to where you want your object to disappear
    {
        disapper(gameObject);
    }

    if (transform.position.x >= 300) //This position is related to when the object will appear again in the start position
    {
        appear(gameObject);
    }
    
    void disappear()
    {
        transform.Find(gameObject).GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
    }

    void appear()
    {
        transform.Find(gameObject).GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
    }
} // Drag this script to 3 of the game object you want them to move. This code is no tested but should work fine.
```